# Riddle: Anger & Frustration

Tags: riddle

Something I made myself, I believe it's 'pretty' easy.

> During the night,
>   on the left I shine white.
>
> During the night,
>   I shine red on the right.
>
> During the day I'm less visible,
>   because of the light.
>
> I lead to anger and frustration,
>   for most of the population.
>
> Humans want to avoid me,
>   and animals can't have me.
>
> Sometimes I'm reversed,
>   but only because of choices in the past.

Can you find out what/who/... I am? Enjoy!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might be..

> **A traffic jam**

During the night,
on the left I shine white.

> Cars coming towards you have white headlights.

During the night,
I shine red on the right.

> Cars going the same way have red taillights.

During the day I'm less visible,
because of the light.

> The lights of the cars are less visible because of sunlight.

I lead to anger and frustration,
for most of the population.

> Traffic jams are not very enjoyable for most people.

Humans want to avoid me,
and animals can't have me.

> Humans try to avoid getting in traffic jams, and animals don't drive cars.

Sometimes I'm reversed,
but only because of choices in the past.

> In some countries the lights will be mirrored, because they drive on the left. The country where you live is a choice you (or your parents, or theirs, etc.) have made in the past.

Comment: I believe this is the right answer

Comment: You sir, are correct :)

Answer (score 6):

Are you

> Reflective pavement markers?
>  Example [white](https://www.seton.com/reflective-pavement-markers-67888.html) and [red](http://www.emedco.com/pavement-marker-rpm12g.html) one

During the night,
on the left I shine white.

During the night,
I shine red on the right.

> Many cities use these to demarcate roads when the same road supports both way traffic

During the day I'm less visible,
because of the light.

> The markers don't shine in daylight

I lead to anger and frustration,
for most of the population.

> These are only visual separators, and drivers can drive over these causing frustration to the rest of the traffic

Humans want to avoid me,
and animals can't have me.

> Folks tend to stick to the correct side of the road; animals don't care

Sometimes I'm reversed,
but only because of choices in the past.

> a) Contractors can mix them up and put them in the wrong order b) different municipalities/countries may use the color in reverse fashion c) left side driving vs right side driving in countries are scenarios in which the colors reverse.

Comment: Very good answer. Just the last point , I think you might be wrong. Clue - England vs France, for example.

Comment: Nice answer, and nice hint from rhsquared

Comment: Good answer, but not what I'm looking for. I didn't even know there were red & white xxxxx of that kind! :D